# Output is not getting as expected in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Not getting an expected output as compared to actual output.
Although the counter here has been placed outside the loop.
Here Marks are printed every after the Righ t Wrong.
I want that it should get printed only once that is at the end. I have written it already outside the if loop

```
resp = {}
ansdb = {}
counter = 0

for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = int(resp_i)

print "<br>"


for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb[int(row[0])] = int(row[1])

print "<br>"

for i in range(1, len(resp)+1):

    if resp[i] == ansdb[i]:
        print "<br>Right"
        counter += 1

   else:
       print "<br>Wrong"

   print "Marks:", counter
```

Actual Output:

```
Right Marks: 1
Right Marks: 2
Wrong Marks: 2
Right Marks: 3
Right Marks: 4
```

Expected:

```
Right 
Right 
Wrong 
Right
Right 
Marks: 4
```

Comment: As indented in the question, it is inside the for loop.

Comment: my mistake..outside if

Comment: Generally - watch out with whitespace. Your `else` clause in the for loop is preceded by less whitespaces than your `if`.

Answer (score 2):

The last line:

```
print "Marks:", counter
```

is inside the for loop, so just correct it, and it should work:

```
resp = {}
ansdb = {}
counter = 0

for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = int(resp_i)

print "<br>"

for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb[int(row[0])] = int(row[1])

print "<br>"

for i in range(1, len(resp)+1):

    if resp[i] == ansdb[i]:
        print "<br>Right"
        counter += 1
    else:
        print "<br>Wrong"

print "Marks:", counter
```

Comment: @user3003685 if your code is working, this should work, too! just move the last line out of the for loop.. I could not test this, because there is one line: form.getvalue and I have no form, I think you are using an MVC like django?!

Answer (score 1):

Move this line out of loop scope.

```
print "Marks:", counter
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the last print statement outside the for loop. Something like this:

```
resp = {}
ansdb = {}
counter = 0

for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = int(resp_i)

print "<br>"


for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb[int(row[0])] = int(row[1])

print "<br>"

for i in range(1, len(resp)+1):

    if resp[i] == ansdb[i]:
        print "<br>Right"
        counter += 1

  else:
       print "<br>Wrong"

print "Marks:", counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works correctly:

```
resp = {}
ansdb = {}
counter = 0

for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = int(resp_i)

print "<br>"


for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb[int(row[0])] = int(row[1])

print "<br>"

for i in range(1, len(resp)+1):
    if resp[i] == ansdb[i]:
        print "<br>Right"
        counter += 1
    else:
        print "<br>Wrong"

print "Marks:", counter
```

Comment: if resp[i] == ansdb[i]:
KeyError: 6
Didn't u get that ??

Comment: technically this is not relevant to what you asked for. KeyError indicated that either ansdb is empty or its length is smaller than that of resp. i assumed both the dictionaries were correctly filled up before printing. i just wanted to make sure you get output in expected format.

Comment: if my outputs are coming proper, its working, but its not in the expected way..thats it

Comment: you can (1) rewrite if resp[i] == ansdb[i] as if ansdb.has_key(i) and (resp[i] == ansdb[i])  (2) you can make sure both the dictionaries are equally filled.